# How to check if a column data from table exist in the same table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, comparison

How can I do this in SQL select statement..

Considering I have this table

```
ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08
AB23 - 11/20 - 11/22
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08
```

You will notice that ID_A=AB23 has two entries and **DATE2 of first line is equal to DATE1 of the second line**, this means that these two lines are connected.

**So, how can I get or create my select statement to view these lines that are connected to each other?**

EDIT:
What I was trying to do in my select statement is this:
a. check DATE2 if is not null
b. from there, check DATE2 if it exists in the DATE1 of whole table and return the value of columns.

What I would like to get should look like this:

```
ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
AB23 - 11/20 - 11/22
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
```

P.S. I was hoping to not do this using a loop.. As this tend to get the server too slow to respond when I get to have too much of data.
 - Let me note that i am comparing columns within the same database..

@fthiella
here is my sample data with the scenario im referring to..

```
ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08
AB23 - 11/20 - 11/22
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08
PQ10 - 11/20 - -n/a-
LM88 - 11/21 - -n/a-
PQ10 - 11/15 - 11/20
```

from there i would like to get these:

```
ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08
```

here's a quick explanation of why i excluded the others:

```
ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08 - not excluded
AB23 - 11/20 - 11/22 - excluded because DATE2 is connected to DATE1 of same ID_A
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01 - not excluded
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08 - not excluded
PQ10 - 11/20 - -n/a- - excluded because DATE2 is null
LM88 - 11/21 - -n/a- - excluded because DATE2 is null
PQ10 - 11/15 - 11/20 - excluded because DATE2 is connected to DATE1 of same ID_A (regardless if DATE2 of that line is null)
```

priority of condition can be - exclude null DATE2 first, then check comparison and exclude those lines that are preceeding other lines..

Sorry for having so much of your time, I really appreciate every help you have given me.. for now this question can be tagged as ANSWERED, thanks again fthiella..

Comment: U can use `ORDER BY` and do not worry about the line. example `ORDER BY ID_A, DATE1`. It will automatically get the result in desired order.

Comment: If I use ORDER BY, I would still see the other two lines in the above example, right? Can you give me a select statement that I could try? What I wish to have are only the lines that are connected.. Thanks for quick reply.. =)

Comment: Why do you have set the VB.NET tag? Do you want a sql based answer or a coded one is acceptable?

Comment: oh sorry about that, i would want the sql based one.  I was trying to code it in VB.NET in my own code so i thought of adding it on the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date1.* FROM DATES date1 JOIN DATES date2 On date1.ID_A = date1.ID_A
WHERE date1.DATE2 = date2.DATE1
UNION
SELECT D2.* FROM DATES date1 JOIN DATES date2 On date1.ID_A = date2.ID_A
WHERE date1.DATE2 = date2.DATE1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT D1.* FROM DATES D1
JOIN DATES D2
On D1.ID_A = D2.ID_A
WHERE D1.DATE2 = D2.DATE1

UNION

SELECT D2.* FROM DATES D1
JOIN DATES D2
On D1.ID_A = D2.ID_A
WHERE D1.DATE2 = D2.DATE1
```

Comment: woah! this works good.. let me have a few more minutes to check if this is perfect.. thanks so much ! =)

Comment: Hello Yograj, in your code, i was trying to invert the code to get my other desired result.. (other than my first request, i was also trying to reverse your code to get the lines that doesn't have proceeding connection)

In the above example, "AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01" doesn't have a DATE2 that proceeds its connection.  So, from the same table.. I would like to get the lines:

ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08

Excluding the line "AB23 - 11/20 - 11/22" because it is preceding the other line "AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01"

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
SELECT
  your_table.*
FROM
  your_table inner join your_table your_table_1
  on your_table.ID_A=your_table_1.ID_A
     and (your_table.DATE2 = your_table_1.DATE1
          or your_table.DATE1 = your_table_1.DATE2)
```

I'm joining `your_table` with itself, using an `inner join`, so it will return rows only if for each row there's a connection (same ID_A, DATE2=DATE1 or DATE1=DATE2).

**EDIT:** and this should give you records that don't have a connection, based on your comment:

```
SELECT your_table.*
FROM
  your_table left join your_table your_table_1
  on your_table.ID_A=your_table_1.ID_A
     and (your_table.DATE2 = your_table_1.DATE1)
WHERE your_table_1.ID_A is null
      and your_table.DATE2 is not null
```

Here I'm joining `your_table` with itself, using a left join, and filtering results with ID_A is null. This means that this query will return every record in your_table, except the ones that have DATE2 equal to a DATE1 in the same table. If DATE2 is null already, the join won't succeed so rows will be returned.

Comment: Hello fthiella,

I was trying to invert the code to get my other desired result.. (other than my first request, i was also trying to reverse it to get the lines that doesn't have proceeding connection)

In the above example, "AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01" doesn't have a DATE2 that proceeds its connection.  So, from the same table.. I would like to get the lines:

ID_A - DATE1 - DATE2
=====================
CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08

Excluding the line "AB23 - 11/20 - 11/22" because it is preceding the other line "AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01"

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila see my updated answer.. it should return the records that you need

Comment: your code only shows the line that does have preceding connection but don't have the one that proceeds it.  What i would also like is to include the other lines e.g. (from the above example)

CD99 - 11/25 - 12/08
AB23 - 11/22 - 12/01
XP72 - 11/23 - 12/08

the DATE2 of these lines doesn't exist in the whole table so there it is. i hope you could still help me, thanks fthiella.. =)

can you make it include the other lines too? thanks.. =)

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila i am not sure i can understand your request... my second query returns CD99, AB23 (just the one with 11/22-12/01, the others has been excluded) and XP72... is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes thats it.. but im not sure why it only returned one - the one with AB23 (11/22-12/01).. all others were excluded.. i have copied the code straight to mine, i wonder what's wrong.. i could not seem to easily understand the joining of tables.. =X.. kindly help me please.. thanks.. =D

Comment: oh i forgot another thing.. i have a scenario where DATE2 is empty.. i would also like to exclude those in the list.. so maybe the code doesn't work because i have lines that don't have DATE2 (null).. i would like to add the condition 'where DATE is not null' somewhere, but im sure this is where i went wrong.. can you help me? thanks again..

Comment: i have made the end of code like this..
.. "WHERE your_table_1.ID_A is null and your_table.ID_A is not null"

but i had two sets of my columns.. >.<.. sorry if im really having a hard time to get a hand of this.. please help

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila i added a little explanation, maybe later i can improve it... do you have some sample data to show? maybe i can understand better...

Comment: ill add my reply to this on the end of my question above.. =)

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila i added a `and your_table.DATE2 is not null` now i think it should work!

Comment: yes.. thank you so much.. but one more problem.. aside from the previous columns, i also get a copy of those columns on the side with no values in it.. ill show you the result in my post above.. how can i get rid of those?

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila sorry i forgot just a `*` that returns all columns of all joined tables, instead of a `your_table.*` that returns just all columns of `your_table`, now it's okay!

Comment: haha.. okay.. this should work.. now i understand where i got it wrong.. =).. thank you so much

EDIT: i'll just edit my added queries above.. thanks again.. =)